# How do I calculate, or measure, all values in a simple A.C. circuit?

Tags: voltage, power, current, formula-derivation

I'm trying to figure out how all the formulae fit together regarding A.C. currents. Given this circuit and equations:

[image]

I figured out the following:

```
E = 120 V (impressed EMF)
L = 0.160 H
X = L * 2π * f = 0.160 * 2π * 60 = 60.319 Ω
Z = X (no resistances, originally the square root of `R^2 + X^2`)
I = E / Z
```

So I have a few questions here:

- Is the value '120V' actually the impressed EMF (total EMF) or is it the power/active component of the EMF?
- How would I calculate the reactive/watt-less EMF?
- Why do all the power formulae need \$I^2\$ or \$E^2\$, where does this come from?
- Is it normal that the resistance of the conductor is not included in the calculations?
- What values would I see if I used a voltmeter, ammeter, watt meter?

Thanks!

Comment: X_L = L * omega = L* 2pi * f, altrough you did insert correct values but formula isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

120V is the RMS voltage of the supplied AC voltage: -

[image]

Power formulas are based on P = VI and ohms law. Ohms law states that V=IR therefore power can be re-written to (IR)I = I\$^2\$R. You can do the same trick for substituting I to get \$V^2\$/R.

> Is it normal that the resistance of the conductor is not included in
>   the calculations?

You can take wire resistance into account if you want but the question raised does not require this nor provide information.

> What values would I see if I used a voltmeter, ammeter, watt meter?

You'd pretty much see what you calculated (I did double check your numbers by the way).

---

Current in a pure inductor: -

Basic formula is Applied Voltage = L\$\dfrac{di}{dt}\$.

(Yes, this seems backwards in that we are wanting to apply a known voltage and derive current but bear with me)....

This means that if the current is a sinewave then the voltage is the mathematical differentiation of a sine wave i.e. a cosine wave: -

[image]

Or, more generally, if you apply a sinewave voltage to a pure inductor then the current "lags" the voltage waveform by 90 degrees or one-quarter of a cycle.

Comment: Thanks! Any tips on calculating the active/reactive components of the EMF and/or current?

Comment: The EMF (applied voltage) is 120 volts and the current is as per your formula E/Z where Z = 2\$\pi\$fL. Current lags applied voltage by a perfect 90 degrees. I've said that but I'm not confident I've said what you think you might want to know?

Comment: I guess a better question would be, how do I calculate the phase angle?

Comment: PS. I'm trying to understand this: https://books.google.be/books?id=m5I003c-PmUC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=reactive+component+emf&source=bl&ots=w_uZTrV-zm&sig=AVSuPzd3xWLraWKG88mEyhv1bMg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHz6uwgKnKAhVDhhoKHazWBwoQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=reactive%20component%20emf&f=false (page 40)

Comment: The way that book is written (the snippet I read) appears to be backwards in its approach. For a pure inductor see my edit to the question but hang on ten minutes while I get there...

Comment: I need your opinions regarding my new question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235531/miscalculation-of-current-for-a-pure-inductive-circuit-in-ltspice