# Settling time for an LR circuit with an AC sine source

Tags: passive-networks

How can we mathematically relate the settling time for an LR circuit with an AC sine source? By settling time I mean the time taken for the circuit reaching to steady state from transient state. This is related to the previous question: [Miscalculation of current for a pure inductive circuit in LTspice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235531/miscalculation-of-current-for-a-pure-inductive-circuit-in-ltspice/235539#235539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using superposition you can treat the transient response (due to initial conditions in your simulation) entirely separately from the ac steady state response to the AC sine source.

In any introductory circuit theory textbook or even in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL_circuit), you can find the basic formula for the zero-input response:

$$i(t) = i(0)\exp(-t/\tau)$$

where \$\tau=\frac{L}{R}\$.

Here the trick is knowing what to plug in for \$i(0)\$. Your simulator sets the initial current through the inductor to 0. But this is the sum of the current due to the steady state response, and due to the transient. You know that the steady state response should give a current of about -2.5 A at \$t=0\$. So that means the part of the initial current due to the zero input response is +2.5 A, and that's the value you should use in the above equation to get the transient part of the simulation result.

Comment: And to focus on the *time* aspect, you can consider the system settled after 3-5 tau (depending on how closely you're counting)

Comment: But ταυ = L/R  becomes infinity if the circuit is pure inductive like in my previews question right? and current will never alternate in theory for a real pure inductive circuit?

Comment: @user16307 If the circuit is *purely* inductive, then it's not a LR circuit (and an impossible theoretical construct at that point). If you set up the initial conditions of your circuit to have a DC current bias as you have done, theoretically that bias will never dissipate without a resistance.

Comment: @W5VO I'm asking because in simulation the circuit does settle to steady state for a pure inductive circuit. Does LTspice add series resistance even-though we don't add any?

Comment: If \$\tau=\infty\$ then \$e^{-t/\tau}=1\$ for all \$t\$, so there is no transient, just a steady state sinusoid.

Comment: @user16307 Yes it does - by default it is 1 mΩ. My version of LTSpice will not simulate with R set to 0 (because you are directly connecting a voltage source to an inductor).

Comment: @Chu The source is AC sine and the circuit is pure L circuit. Since there is superposition the total current will be i(0)+ i(0)*cos(wt) so the current will not be negative ever right? see my previous question:http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235531/miscalculation-of-current-for-a-pure-inductive-circuit-in-ltspice/235539#235539

Comment: Can any one write the superposition sum of transient and steady state? So we can see in the case of R = 0 or pure L how the current behaves.. i wrote i(0)+ i(0)*cos(wt) but im not expert in the field

Comment: For a sine voltage input, the sinusoidal current must be symmetrical about the time axis because the inductor must generate a voltage in opposition to the input.

Comment: @Chu can you write a mathematical expression such as i(0)+ i(0)*cos(wt) which would both include steady state and transient for a pure inductive circuit? so that we can see if the current will alternate signs or not. is it too hard?

Comment: If \$v=sin(\omega t)\$, \$i=-\frac{1}{\omega L}cos(\omega t)\$, if initial conditions are zero.

Comment: @Chu that doesnt match with the simulation. in simulation current never alternates or should i say it swings always above zero. i dont get this

Comment: @Chu What you wrote looks like only steady state part. Is that?

Comment: What are inductance value and frequency?

Comment: There is no transient, just steady state sinusoid. There must be something wrong with the simulation. If there's an initial steady current, that will continue without decaying, as there's no resistance to dissipate power.

Comment: @user16307, you are correct. If there is no loss, the inductor current becomes roughly \$2.5 - 2.5\cos(\omega{}t)\$. This is because you're not simulating the response to \$v(t)=\sin(\omega t)\$. You're actually simulating the response to \$v(t)=u(t)\sin(\omega t)\$.

Comment: @ThePhoton I messed up this question, people might not make sense what I'm trying to understand please see my new question if possible: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235616/ac-transient-analysis-for-lr-series-circuit-for-a-given-ac-source

Answer (score 1):

A circuit output settles for a the DC source excitation, the AC source shall never let the output settle as time tends to infinity.