# Current and Voltage in an Inductor with an AC source!

Tags: ac, inductor, electromagnetism

This is the simulation of a RL circuit with an AC source.

That AC source is connected with the circuit at the moment when the source voltage has zero phase angle with 5 volts peak.

It can be seen from the simulation that the peak voltage of the first half cycle (which is the transient I know) is less than the peak voltage of the negative half cycle and rest of the cycles.

I want to know whether that the peak voltage of the positive half cycle is less than the peak voltage of the rest of the cycles is because of any simulation error or is there any other reason?

Plus

When the value of the resistor is increased the transient current and voltage die off more quickly.

Please anyone tell me that why increasing resistance makes the transient to die off quicker?

Infact why resistance make the transients to die off?

I need detail answers of these question. So please if anybody can help!

[image]

Comment: I think that almost the exact same question was asked here this week and has good answers.

Comment: nope. i didnt ask such a question before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current waveform in an inductor with AC source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495862/current-waveform-in-an-inductor-with-ac-source)

Comment: ^^ really the same question, please read the answers there, and ask based on what isn't answered there, if questions remain!

Comment: that question is different and the answers do not answer this question.

Comment: What transient?

Comment: @Alex the answers you've gotten include formulas. They answer your question.

Comment: may be you get the answers there but i dont, let anyone answer this question please.

Comment: Your first question is unclear. What voltage are you referring to. Maybe draw a circuit or explain in clearer terms.

Comment: the peak voltage of the first positive half cycle is less than the peak negative voltage of the second half cycle. you can see the vertical lines at these two points in tthe simulation @Andyaka

Comment: The first half cycle is in the transient period. For the remainder of the graph the transient has dissipated.

Comment: Notice that putting a resistor in series with the inductor you make a "voltage divider" thus VL is no longer equal to Vin so, the current will no longer "rise so fast" and it cannot reach 2*Vin/XL due to voltage drop aross resistor.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235616/ac-transient-analysis-for-lr-series-circuit-for-a-given-ac-source

Comment: @Alex What voltage are you plotting - is it the voltage across the inductor? Do you understand the current waveform shape? Concentrate on understanding the current then the voltage becomes easy. So, do you understand the current waveform?

Comment: yes thats the voltage across the inductor. the magnitude of the current also become less and less according to the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this and the related question you asked last week ([Current waveform in an inductor with AC source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/495862/250420)), I think maybe what would help you more is general guidance, rather than specific help with homework.

To that end, what you need in order to understand these circuit problems is

1. An understanding of how to set up and solve the mathematical equations
2. A working knowledge of the solutions to some standard, common circuit configurations such as this one
3. An intuitive grasp of why the solutions are the solutions and what they mean

To this end, I suggest you work through this 'roadmap':

1. Learn how to write the voltage drop across resistors, capacitors, and inductors, in both the time domain and the Laplace/Frequency domain.
2. Learn how to set up Kirchoff's Voltage and Current Laws so you can write an equation that governs the circuit. For the questions you have asked so far, it is the voltage law you need.
3. Learn how to solve those equations
4. Study the solutions and also read about them, and ask yourself the same questions you are asking here. As Ben Hogan use to say about learning the golf swing, sometimes you just have to 'pound it out in the dirt.'

This seems like a lot of work, but that is what becoming an engineer is.